# p-value of observation in non-parametric distribution

Tags: p-value, frequentist

The question is really naive but i'm stucked in...
I'll eliminate all the biological details and experiments and quote just the problem at hand. I would like to know  how to proceed. If the data (or my explanation) isn't clear enough, I'll try to explain better by editing.

I have a distribution like:

[image]

I've tried to fit it into a "standard"(normal,exponential ...) distribution using R (fitdistr from MASS package followed kolmogorov-smirnov test to known the goodness of fit), without results

I simple would like to known what's the p-value of obtain an observation > 300 given the distribution. If data where normaly distributed i could use a Z-test but this distribution doesn't

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Could you provide data example for your question? Why do you say that any parametric distribution cannot be used to approximate your data?

Comment: The distribution are composed by more than 35000 observations, so i don't known an easy way to provide you the data. I have try to fit the distribution using MASS and vcd packages in R, testing goodness of fiting. The distribution doesn't fit in any "standard" distribution (is not normal (obviusly), is not exponential ...)

Comment: Why do you think is does not follow a parametric distribution? Did you try to find best lambda for exponential? You can always find a p-value using the formal definition of p-value (part of numbers that are higher/lower, etc.) for any distribution.

Comment: Try 0-inflated exponential. Also you can almost never fit a distribution using real data, but it does not mean that modelling with the distribution (may be with not a best fit) is useless.

Comment: How i can fit to 0-inflated exponential using R?

Comment: I did not find any out-of-the-box solution, however, I would suggest that you should vary your number of zeros in a loop (for example, for ($i$ in seq(0:25000))), and try to fit exponential to your distribution with $i$ number of zeros. I guess that you have too many 0's because of experimental error or smth, your data seems clearly exponential. But the other alternative - use the definition of p-value for any non-parametric distribution.

Comment: Vary the number of zeros ss a good solution, thank you, and in the bad case i would use it, but in this case, zeros are very relevant and i cannot remove it. I don't known how to use p-values in non-parametric distributions

Comment: Just look at the proportion of values that are bigger than yours. If your value is between lower tail of 95% of observations and upper tail of 5%, the p-value of the observation is 0.05. Please look [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/P-value_in_statistical_significance_testing.svg/1024px-P-value_in_statistical_significance_testing.svg.png).

Comment: What do you intend to convey when you say the distribution of the observations is nonparametric?